# Codeceptjs unirest helper

Tags: unirest, codeceptjs

Framework - codeceptjs.
I want to send api request to my aplication:
 I.sendPostRequest
 I.sendGetRequest
etc.

I install unirest library. What i must do next? How to write a helper for these functions?

Answer (score 1):

Install inirest with: `npm install unirest -g`

to delete:
`await I.sendDeleteRequest(url)`

to post:

```
await I.sendPostRequest(url, null, {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
})
```